# Cucumber steps definitions in spanish: Ambiguous match of "..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara, gherkin

I'm trying to translate the steps definitions of cucumber to spanish but I'm getting this error:

```
Ambiguous match of "que estoy en la página "inicio de sesión""


  features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:3:in `/^que estoy en la página "([^"]*)"$/'
  features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:7:in `/^visito la pa|ágina "([^"]*)"$/'
```

Here's my web_steps.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8

Dado /^que estoy en la página "([^"]*)"$/ do |page|
  visit(path_to page)
end

Cuando /^visito la página "([^"]*)"$/ do |page|
  visit(path_to page)
end
```

How can that be ambiguos if I got the ^ and the $ in the regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's seeing a `|` in the latter step definition. Look closely at the second line of the error:

```
features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:3:in `/^que estoy en la página "([^"]*)"$/'
features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:7:in `/^visito la pa|ágina "([^"]*)"$/'
```

It's seeing `/^visito la pa|ágina "([^"]*)"$/`, which it interprets as an OR, i.e. `/^visito la pa` OR `ágina "([^"]*)"$/`. With that interpretation, the match does indeed become ambiguous.

Now why it is reading it that way is a mystery to me, perhaps some UTF-8 garbling?

Comment: Actually I removed the | in the step definition when I post it here. The bar is in there. I thought that is was going to accept pagina or página not half of the phrase. Thanks, it's solved now.